# Pip does not work: Python 3.10 error on Arch Linux

Tags: pip, package, archlinux

When I'm trying to use pip/pip3 to install some packages, I get this error every time. How can I fix it?

I already tried to reinstall *python-pip*, *python3*, and *python*:

```
sudo pacman -Rcns python-pip
sudo pacman -Rcns python
sudo pacman -S python
sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

But still it gives me this error:

```
pip install cryptography

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 315, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 98, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/__init__.py", line 75, in get_default_environment
    return select_backend().Environment.default()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/__init__.py", line 63, in select_backend
    from . import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/pkg_resources.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3277, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3278, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2785, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2284, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2217, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pygoogle/google.py", line 113
    print """PyGoogle %(__version__)s
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution. The `pygoogle` package was not interpretable. Whenever I tried to use pip for anything "list, install ...", it was giving me this strange error.

I've got the solution here:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (or pygoogle path in your error)
sudo rm -rf pygoogle/ pygoogle.pth   (or remove pygoogle related files)
ls |grep pygoogle
pip2 install pygoogle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try *uninstalling* *python*, then installing *python3* and *python3-pip*, and then use `pip3 install cryptography`.

Comment: This is not working